# Java JavaFX deployment allow user to select installation path

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, ant, inno-setup

I am working on a desktop application using Eclipse Oxygen with JavaFX. I have been following a JavaFX tutorial about how to deploy my Java application into a .exe file. http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/ The tutorial does not show how to allow the use to specify the installation path when installing their application.

At the moment when I install the app it is just extracted into a user's AppData folder

In my application I have a build folder which contains a deploy folder, a build.xml file, and a build.fxbuild file. I think somewhere in these files I am supposed to add the settings. It is also using Ant and I had to install Inno Setup

Comment: @Martin Prikryl Yes I meant to say `AppData/Local` I have updated it.

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/89

Comment: I am not using that plugin. I am using e(fx)clipse extension: http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/